# ON DUPLICATE KEY creating new records

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a bunch of product info from the Amazon API. I'm using the ASIN as my primary key. When running an `INSERT` I'd like to check if it exists, if so, update a few values and move on. I don't want duplicate records.

Here is a code snippet:

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("
        INSERT INTO products(ASIN, Many, Other, Values)
        VALUES(:ASIN, :Many, :Other, :Values)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Other= :Other
        ")

$stmt->execute(array(
                        ':ASIN'     =>  $ASIN,
                        ':Many'     =>  $many,
                        ':Other'    =>  $other,
                        ':Values'   =>  $values
               ));
```

This simply adds duplicate records to my db. How can I check the ASIN and if it's a duplicate, update it with any new info?

Comment: "The Amazon Standard Identification Number (ASIN) is a 10-character alphanumeric unique identifier assigned by Amazon.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the keys in your database as unique or primary keys, otherwise the engine will not know if it is a duplicate key or not.

Comment: The ASIN is set as the primary key

Comment: Might be worth including a `SHOW CREATE TABLE products` in your post.

Comment: I changed it to unique and it seems to be working now. Thanks for the tip